Doors DXL how to read and parse a CSV file?
I have a CSV file with only two columns that I would like to parse out.  The first column of the CSV file is the absolute ID of an object in one (source) module and the second column is the absolute ID of an object in another (destination) module.  I will be using the data entries to create DOORS links via DXL.
How do I parse the CSV file in a DOORS DXL language so that I can use the information in my script?

As a giveaway of the day and since I did not find a solution online, use this file & functions to get you started.
// Support import of information from CSV files
/*
 * Support import of information from CSV files
 * 
 * V:\Development\includes\CSVFileImport.inc
 *
 * Revision History:
 * Version 0.0
 * Created on: 2008-04-16 11:31:15
 * Created by: Ruediger Kaffenberger, TKRE (ruediger.kaffenberger@muc.mtu.com)
 *
 */

XFLAGS_ &= ~AutoDeclare_

void updateModuleAttriutes(Module)
/*******************************************************************************
 * Global Variables
 */

int     nRow
Stream  stCSV
Skip    skColumnHeaders       = null
int     nColumn
Skip    skRowData     = null

const Regexp  reQuotes1
const Regexp  reQuotes2
const   Regexp  reAnything  = regexp ".*"

char    cDoubleQuote   = '\"'

Buffer  bWork = null

/*******************************************************************************
 * impSprRemoveDoubleQuotes
 *
 */

string impSprRemoveDoubleQuotes(Buffer buff) {
    Buffer temp
    string result
    int    i        = 0
    int    buff_len = length buff
    bool   found    = false

    if (buff_len == 0)
        return ""

    temp = create()

    if (buff[0] == cDoubleQuote)
        i++

    while (i < buff_len) {
        if (buff[i] == cDoubleQuote) {
            if (found) {
                found = false
            } else {
                temp += buff[i]
                found = true
            }
        } else {
            temp += buff[i]
        }
        i++
    }


    buff_len = length temp
    if (temp[buff_len - 1] == cDoubleQuote)
        result = temp[0:buff_len - 2] ""
    else
        result = temp[0:buff_len - 3] ""

    delete temp

    return result

} /* impSprRemoveDoubleQuotes */


/*******************************************************************************
 * impSprHasEvenNumDoubleQuotes
 *
 */

bool impSprHasEvenNumDoubleQuotes(Buffer buff) {
    int    i     = 0
    int    count = 0

    if (length buff == 0)
        return false

    while (i < length buff) {
        if (buff[i] == cDoubleQuote)
            count++
        i++
    }

    if (count%2 == 0)
        return true
    else
        return false

} /* impSprHasEvenNumDoubleQuotes */


/*******************************************************************************
 * impSprGetToken
 *
 */

string impSprGetToken(Stream file, Buffer &bLine, char cSep, bool bPreserve_nl) {
    string  token = ""
    Buffer b = create()
    
    setempty(b)

    if (bLine[0] == cSep) {
        bLine = tempStringOf(bLine[1:])
        token = ""
    } else if (bLine[0] == cDoubleQuote) {
        setempty bWork
        while (!impSprHasEvenNumDoubleQuotes(bWork)) {
            if (reQuotes1(bLine)) {
                bWork += tempStringOf(bLine[0:end 0])
                bLine = tempStringOf(bLine[(end 0) + 1:])
            } else {
                bWork += tempStringOf(bLine[0:(length bLine) - 1])
                bLine = ""
            }
            if (!impSprHasEvenNumDoubleQuotes(bWork) && tempStringOf(bLine) == "") {
                file >= b
                bLine = tempStringOf(b)
                nRow++
                if (bPreserve_nl)
                    bWork += "\n"
            }
        }
        token = impSprRemoveDoubleQuotes(bWork)
    } else if (reQuotes2 bLine) {
        token = tempStringOf(bLine[0:(end 0) - 1])
        bLine = tempStringOf(bLine[(end 0) + 1:])
    } else if (reAnything(bLine) && (end 0) == (length(bLine) - 1)) {
        token = tempStringOf(bLine[0:end 0])
        bLine = ""
    }
    delete b
    return token

} // impSprGetToken 


/*******************************************************************************
 * impSprReadRow
 *
 */

bool impSprReadRow(Stream stCSV, char cSep, Skip skRowData, int &i, bool bPreserve_nl) 
{
    string token = ""
    Buffer bData = create()

    if (end stCSV)
        return false

    stCSV >= bData
    nRow++

    while (tempStringOf(bData) != "") {
        token = impSprGetToken(stCSV, bData, cSep, bPreserve_nl)
        put(skRowData, i++, token)
    }

    if (!end stCSV && null token)
    {
        put(skRowData, i++, token)
    }

    if (i == 0) {
        delete bData
        return false
    }

    if (i < nColumn) {
        while (i < nColumn)
            put(skRowData, i++, "")
    }

    delete bData
    return true

} // impSprReadRow

void importFromCSVFile(Module m, string sFile, char cSep, LogFile logFile)
{
    pragma runLim, 0
    bWork = create()
    reportInformation(logFile << "Import from CSV file " << sFile)
    if (!fileReadable_ sFile)
    {
        reportError(logFile << "Can not read file " << sFile)
        return
    }
    updateModuleAttributes(m)

    stCSV = read sFile
    nRow = 0
    Buffer b = create()
    while(!end(stCSV))
    {
        stCSV >= b
        ++nRow 
    }
    close(stCSV)
    stCSV = read sFile
    
    reQuotes1 = regexp "[^\"]*\"" cSep ""
    reQuotes2 = regexp "[^" cSep "]*" cSep ""
    
    if (!null skColumnHeaders)
        delete skColumnHeaders
    skColumnHeaders = create()
    nColumn = 0
    
    if (!impSprReadRow(stCSV, cSep, skColumnHeaders, nColumn, false)) 
    {
        reportError(logFile << "No data to load in file " << sFile)
        return
    } 
    Skip skAttributes = create()
    string sColumnHeader
    for sColumnHeader in skColumnHeaders do
    {
        int nColumn = (int(key(skColumnHeaders)))
        string sAttribute
        if (find(skColumnHeader2Attribute, sColumnHeader, sAttribute))
        {
            put(skAttributes, nColumn, sAttribute)
        }
    }
    Object o = last(m)
    if (null o)
        o = create(m)
    progressStart(getUI(), "CORE Import, from CSV", "", nRow)
    bool bDone = false
    int nRow = 1
    while (!end stCSV) 
    {
        progressStep(nRow)
        progressMessage(nRow "")
        if (!null skRowData)
            delete skRowData
        skRowData = create()
        nColumn = 0
        int i = 0
        if (impSprReadRow(stCSV, cSep, skRowData, i, true)) 
        {
            string sValue
            for sValue in skRowData do
            {
                int n = (int key(skRowData))
                string sAttribute
                if (find(skAttributes, n, sAttribute))
                    transferCellContent(o, sAttribute, sValue, logFile)
            }
        }
        if (progressCancelled())
        {
            reportError(logFile << "Import aborted by user after " << nRow "" << " Requirements")
            break
        }
        i = 0
        o = create(o)
        ++nRow
    }
    reportSuccess(logFile << "Imported " << nRow "" << " Requirements")
    progressStop()
    delete bWork
    delete skAttributes
    delete skColumnHeaders
    return
}


Thanks for the thorough example solution!
